# Collection object is missing if model state fails. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, argumentnullexception

I have a `Model` which contains properties and `ICollection` of files.

```
[Required]
public int SerialNo { get; set; }

public Type Type {get; set;}
[Required]
public int TypeId

public virtual ICollection<Files> Files { get; set; }
```

Now, I am on my Edit Screen, and if Model State is not valid I pass my object again to the view. Like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return View(MyClass);
}
```

I am getting `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` for Files Collection. How can I attach my Files Collection again with my object?

**Modified:** Use of Collection Files:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
  <p> @item.Location </p>                  
}
```

The problem is File is `Null`.

Comment: make sure that is posted back with values, not `null`

Comment: How can I do that? Using `Include`?

Comment: Are your generating form controls for each property of each `Files` in the collection? If not, just call the db to get them again as you did in the GET method

Comment: Yes I am generating the form controls.

Comment: Then they will not be `null` and you will not get that error, so it suggests the code in your view is wrong - but we cant see it :)

Comment: Should I post my complete code here?

Comment: In my `view`, I am looking through the collection and displaying data. But, when `model-state` is not valid and I send back my object the collection is `null`.

Comment: @AshirK. You need to show how you generate the form controls for the properties in your `Files` collection (your clearly not doing it correctly)

Comment: Basically, I am not generating form controls. I am just looping through and showing data. I have updated my question.

Comment: I got the Problem. I was not sending back to Edit Action. Now I am sending but it's counting as 0, when there are files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167163/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ashir-k).